# How can I access video element properties in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

I cannot access the video element properties until I have played the video.

I am currently checking the video duration in `ngOnInit` and `NaN` value is being returned.

My lines of code to get duration are:

HTML:

```
<video src="myvid.mp4" #vid></video>
```

TypeScript:

```
    @ViewChild('vid') vid: ElementRef
    ngOnInit(){
      //vid is of type ElementRef
      this.duration = this.vid.nativeElement.duration
    }
```

Comment: Hello Hussein, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add your question in title and post ? Question is a sentence terminated by ? character. I have also changed the format of your document to add some empty lines and highlight special terms. You can edit my change again to make what you want. It is only an exemple for you.

Comment: I'm not Javascript specialist but is that normal that ; character is missing after duration ?

Comment: What does you html look like? Is duration an attribute?

Comment: ... and how are you setting this.vid?

Comment: Javascript works without semicolons

Comment: @schlebe this code should actually be in Typescript, which compiles down to JavaScript. Neither typescript nor JavaScript require the use of semicolons and it is actually a large debate on which is better (with or without). My personal stance it that you should use them, but that is for a different question.

Comment: I am grabbing the video element using angular's template variable(#vid). I then access this in my component using ViewChild

Comment: @Hussein can you show both your typescript and html code that are involved in the question?

Comment: As: @ViewChild('vid') vid: ElementRef

Comment: Ok. Please wait

Answer (score 1):

The video's metadata is not being loaded so properties such as `duration` cannot be accessed until the video is played. To load the metadata, add the `preload` attribute of the video element with the value `metadata`. You should then add an event handler for the `loadedmetadata` event. Here are the changes I have made:

HTML

```
<video src="myvid.mp4" preload="metadata" (loadedmetadata)="vidProps($event)"></video>
```

TypeScript

```
@ViewChild('vid') vid: ElementRef
vidProps(event){
    this.duration = event.srcElement.duration
}
```